# Is there a way to only invisible ItemTemplate of ListView?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I find `IsVisible` attribute only in the `<ListView>` itself but don't find in neither `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` nor `<ListView.Header>`, So is there a way to only invisible `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` and keep `<ListView.Header>` visible?

Comment: Why not to remove an item from the list instead of hiding it?

Comment: As I want to show them again if user taps something, So IsVisible-like attribute will be much better in performance.

Comment: Sounds like you have performance issues that you should solve instead of trying to create hacks.I would recommend to keep it simple and remove the items that should not be represented by the ListView.

Comment: No I don't have but I think IsVisible-like attribute is better than removing/readding items, Isn't it?

Comment: Link to official docs regarding ListView performance considerations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance

Comment: sounds like you are trying to collapse a listiview, though this is not built in, as @EvZ said, you need to add and remove the items on the header tap. Take a look at [ExpandableView](https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/ExpandableView)

Comment: I've 2 ListViews on top of each other I want if user does action the ItemTemplate of the 1st not only disappear but also the blank area it leaves disappear so the header of the 2nd list comes very below header of 1st list, that's why VerticalOption of them Start and StartAndExpand respectively, but the screen is divided equally over them though.